# Use of hosts in ansible_ssh_common_args

Tags: ssh, ansible, ansible-inventory

I'm using aws_ec2.yml to query AWS and create my inventory. I've setup the vars section of the inventory file as follows to allow use of a bastion host:

```
[dev:vars]
ansible_ssh_common_args="-o ProxyCommand=\"ssh -q username@1.2.3.4 -o IdentityFile=~/.ssh/keyfile -o Port=22 -W %h:%p\""
ansible_ssh_private_key_file=~/.ssh/keyfile
ansible_user=username
```

I was wondering if it would be possible to replace `1.2.3.4` in the `ansible_ssh_common_args` with a variable/hostname from `aws_ec2.yml` itself, specifically another host lets say `tag_Name_dev_bastion`. Is it possible to use variables/hostnames from within the inventory file in the common_args itself?

Answer (score 0):

It's been 2 months, so you've possibly resolved it by now (I hope)...
But in case you haven't, I've recently started making ample use of the `aws_ec2` Dynamic Inventory, and this is exactly what I was puzzling over for some time.

So say for example purposes I have an aws vpc with a single bastion ec2 in a Public-subnet and a single webserver ec2 in a Private-subnet, to access the private ec2 I need to jump from the public bastion. 
I also have a dynamic inventory called `inventory.aws_ec2.yml`,

```
---
plugin: aws_ec2

regions:
  - eu-west-1

filters:
  tag:Group:
    - bastion
    - webserver_node
  instance-state-name: running

keyed_groups:
  - key: tags.Group
    separator: ''

hostnames:
  - network-interface.association.public-ip
  - network-interface.addresses.private-ip-address
```

You can get a nice high level output of that using:
 `ansible-inventory inventory.aws_ec2.yml --list`

This output should include a bunch of `hostvars` for each host returned by your inventory, and an overview of the host groups and their hosts. Lovely stuff!

Using this information is possible with ✨[magic variables](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_vars_facts.html#information-about-ansible-magic-variables)✨
We know the data we want is in `hostvars` so we can go the following route:
`project/group_vars/webserver_node.yml`

```
---
# SSH / ProxyJump
ansible_user: username
ansible_ssh_private_key_file: ~/.ssh/aws_demo_key
ansible_ssh_common_args: >- 
  -o ProxyCommand="ssh
  -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no
  -o UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null
  -W %h:%p
  -q {{ ansible_user }}@{{ hostvars[groups["bastion"][0]]["public_ip_address"] }}"
```

Then when you run the playbook on the `webserver_node` host, It will jump correctly!

Hope this helps!
*I found my answer from this [Serverfault answer](https://serverfault.com/a/639269)*